# Running projects without Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

In my company, plenty of teams (including mine) don't know how to run Spring projects without Eclipse to a point that this is becoming a problem. I've extensively searched around for stuff, but stumbling upon places just saying "press Run" for the project to be ran. Many times that doesn't help us understand the dependencies of legacy projects, and of course, legacy projects have no documentation laying around, or the folks who designed it (or the folks who designed it don't know how to run that without the IDE).

Here is the architecture of the latest one:
Spring, Gradle, Java.

I've tried running this project with `./gradlew run`, but the task run doesn't seem supposed to run the application, the task doesn't even exist and the `build.gradle` file doesn't have it.

This is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.name'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
}
```

This is the Java file that is suppose to be the runner:

```
package com.company.authApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Even if the `build.gradle` file mentiones `mavenCentral()`, this is not build for Maven at all, that's just the default structure for it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `./gradlew bootRun`? You might try to generate the jar also. Did you look at `./gradlew tasks`?

Comment: thanks! That actually launched Spring but it failed. I'll keep checking on it.

Comment: build the jar/war using gradle and run it with " java -jar <jar-name>.jar/<war-name>.war"

Comment: Yeah, building the jar using gradle is proving difficult as well. I'll share if I find anything else, thanks, @MaxExplode.